# POST request through AJAX not recognized in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery

I am trying to send some post data from a form to PHP to be validated and send an email if the data is valid. My form is below with the appropriate jQuery ajax code:

```
<h1><a href="#" onclick="show_form();">Send Invitation</a></h1>
<form id="invitation-form" action="" method="post">
<p>
    Your Email Address<br />
    <input type="text" name="your_email" />
</p>
<p>
    Email Address of Recipient<br />
    <input type="text" name="friends_email" />
</p>
<p>
    Subject<br />
    <input type="text" name="subject" />
</p>
<p>
    Message<br/>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="20" name="message">' . $post_url . '</textarea>
</p>
<input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="sendinvitation" />
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" /></p>
</form>
<div id="note"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#invitation-form").submit(function() {
    alert("submit has fired");
    var str = jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://127.0.1.1/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/send-invitation/send_email.php",
        data: str,
        success: function(message) {
            jQuery("#note").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
                var result = "";
                if ( message == "OK" ) {
                    result = "Your message was sent successfully";
                }
                else if (message == "NOT OK") {
                    result = "Email could not be sent";
                }
                else {
                    result = "Email could not be sent because of unknown reason";
                }
                jQuery(this).html(result);
            });
        }
    });
    alert("After post");
    return false; // Disables submit button from sending a real request
});
</script>
```

My request is successfully sent to send_email.php however I do not seem to get any POST data or GET data for that matter. My code for the send_email.php file is here:

```
<?php
require_once('send-invitation.php');

if (isset($_POST)) {
    $post_url = get_post_url();
    echo("Before send invitation");
    sendinvitation_form_action($post_url);
    echo("After send invitation");

    echo("Back in send email");
}

function get_post_url() {
    global $post;
    $blog_id = get_option('page_for_posts');
    $post_id = '';

    if (is_home($blog_id)) {
        $post_id = $blog_id;
    } else {
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }

    return get_permalink($post_id);
}
?>
```

The code that handles the form data is inside a class and looks like this:

```
public function sendinvitation_form_action($post_url) {
    $action = '';
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST' )
    {
        error_log('Show Form', 0);
        $action = $this->sendinvitation_get_form($post_url);
    }
    else if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
        error_log('Handle Form', 0);
        $action = $this->sendinvitation_handle_submit($post_url);
    }
    return $action;
}

public function sendinvitation_handle_submit() {
    error_log('Inside handle_submit', 0);
    $success = __('OK');
    $error = __('NOT OK');
    if ( isset( $_POST['form_type'] ) and ( $_POST['form_type'] == 'sendinvitation' ) ) {
        try {
            error_log('Inside if', 0);
            $to = $_POST['friends_email'];
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];

            // TODO Suppress error message with @
            error_log("Before sending email");
            error_log("$to $subject $message", 0);
            $send_result = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);
            error_log($send_result, 0);
            $feedback = $send_result ? $success : $error;
        }
        catch( Exception $e ) {

            $feedback = "Catch: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        $feedback = "Error: " . $error;
    }
    error_log($feedback, 0);
    echo $feedback;
}
```

What happens above is that `$this->sendinvitation_get_form($post_url);` is called instead of `$this->sendinvitation_handle_submit($post_url);`.

I am at my wits end why this is happening. This is in relation to a WordPress plugin I am writing but thought this more to do with JS and PHP than WordPress.

Thanks in advance.
nav

Comment: Try using firebug or fiddler to confirm that the post data is being sent to the php page.

Comment: A few (potentially incorrect) thoughts:  I'm thinking `if (isset($_POST)) {` needs to be something else since $_POST is likely always set. I end up using `!empty()` instead. Also, I'm not sure if your browser will decide that 127.0.0.1 and localhost are different origins, but watch out for that too.

Comment: I suggest reading this article on [The right way to use AJAX in WordPress](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/).  The methods you are using fall under his category of "bad use of ajax in WordPress".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are failing on a `function not defined` error at the following line.

```
$blog_id = get_option('page_for_posts');
```

Since you call send_email.php file directly, and it doesn't include any of the Wordpress includes, that function is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have modified my code above as said in  the 5 tips article with some help from an another [article](http://byronyasgur.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/frontend-forward-facing-ajax-in-wordpress/) referenced on the wordpress codex page for [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and it works flawlessly.